# cocoon nested_form add fields above the existing objects in edit.html.erb instead below

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

My new.html.erb is working fine.

But in my edit.html.erb, let's say I have 3 existing departments...

Whenever I click the add department link (to add another field), it keeps on going above the existing departments instead of going below.

btw, my association says that division has many departments and departments belong to division.

In my controller: there goes my new and edit methods

```
def new
    @division = Division.new
     @division.departments.build 
  end

 def edit
    @division = Division.find(params[:id])

  end
```

I require the cocoon js file so I'm using the default and not overriding something else.

**cocoon.js**

```
(function($) {

  function replace_in_content(content, regexp_str, with_str) {
    reg_exp = new RegExp(regexp_str);
    content.replace(reg_exp, with_str);
  }

  function trigger_removal_callback(node) {
    node.parent().parent().trigger('removal-callback');
  }

  $('.add_fields').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this                 = $(this),
        assoc                 = $this.data('association'),
        assocs                = $this.data('associations'),
        content               = $this.data('template'),
        insertionMethod       = $this.data('association-insertion-method') || $this.data('association-insertion-position') || 'before';
        insertionNode         = $this.data('association-insertion-node'),
        insertionCallback     = $this.data('insertion-callback'),
        removalCallback       = $this.data('removal-callback'),
        regexp_braced         = new RegExp('\\[new_' + assoc + '\\]', 'g'),
        regexp_underscord     = new RegExp('_new_' + assoc + '_', 'g'),
        new_id                = new Date().getTime(),
        newcontent_braced     = '[' + new_id + ']',
        newcontent_underscord = '_' + new_id + '_',
        new_content           = content.replace(regexp_braced, '[' + new_id + ']');

    if (new_content == content) {
        regexp_braced     = new RegExp('\\[new_' + assocs + '\\]', 'g');
        regexp_underscord = new RegExp('_new_' + assocs + '_', 'g');
        new_content       = content.replace(regexp_braced, '[' + new_id + ']');
    }

    new_content = new_content.replace(regexp_underscord, newcontent_underscord);

    if (insertionNode){
      insertionNode = insertionNode == "this" ? $this : $(insertionNode);
    } else {
      insertionNode = $this.parent();
    }

    var contentNode = $(new_content);

    // allow any of the jquery dom manipulation methods (after, before, append, prepend, etc)
    // to be called on the node.  allows the insertion node to be the parent of the inserted
    // code and doesn't force it to be a sibling like after/before does. default: 'before'
    insertionNode[insertionMethod](contentNode);

    $this.parent().trigger('insertion-callback');
  });

  $('.remove_fields.dynamic').live('click', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    trigger_removal_callback($this);
    e.preventDefault();
    $this.closest(".nested-fields").remove();
  });

  $('.remove_fields.existing').live('click', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    trigger_removal_callback($this);
    e.preventDefault();
    $this.prev("input[type=hidden]").val("1");
    $this.closest(".nested-fields").hide();
  });

})(jQuery);
```

In my _form.html.erb

```
<div class="new-div-box">
<%= simple_form_for [:admin, @division]  do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name, :label => "Division Name"%>

<div>
<div>

  <%= f.simple_fields_for :departments do |department| %>
  <%= render 'department_fields', :f => department %>

  <% end %>
</div>
  <%=link_to_add_association "Add Department", f, :departments,class: "btn btn-inverse" %>
</div>

  <%= f.submit  :class=>"btn btn-primary submit_btn_division" %>

<% end %>

</div>
```

And the one which I rendered is _department_fields.html.erb

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <%= f.input :name, :label => "Department Name"  %>
  <%= link_to_remove_association raw("<img src='../../../assets/remove.png' width='25px' height='25px'>"), f %>
</div>
```

I wonder why the newly added field goes above the existing fields in my edit.html.erb

Answer (score 4):

I think it looks for a div with the association as the id that wraps the nested fields for.

So your view

```
<div id="departments">
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :departments do |department| %>
    <%= render 'department_fields', :f => department %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="links">
    <%=link_to_add_association "Add Department", f, :departments,class: "btn btn-inverse" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

@spullen's solution would work, but his reasoning is not correct. If you trace thru coccon's code you'll come across something like this

```
var getInsertionNodeElem = function(insertionNode, insertionTraversal, $this){
    if (!insertionNode){
      return $this.parent();
    }
    ...
}
```

and then I believe that this `var addedContent = insertionNodeElem[insertionMethod](contentNode);` adds in the new node.

The point is that the new partial will be inserted above `link_to_add_association`'s parent node. So `link_to_add_association`'s `<a>` element and the new input fields' container node will be siblings.

If you want the inserted partial to be below, `link_to_add_association` must be wrapped in its own div. Example:

```
  <div id="workout-fields">
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :workouts, validate: true do |workout| %>
      <%= render partial: 'shared/workout/form', locals: {f: workout, show_remove: false} %>
    <% end %>
    <div><%= link_to_add_association 'add workout', f, :workouts, partial: 'shared/workout/form'%></div> <!-- this wrapper is IMPORTANT for insertion ordering -->
  </div>
```